# trying to change text color with this function in react native

Tags: react-native

this is the whole document, i'm trying to change "Text Here" text color with a JS function a friend wrote for web. i'd be pretty happy if the text color scanned/pulsed/fluttered through the rainbow instead of the random movement thru picked colors i've got. i'm really just trying to learn how to do this sort of thing in react-native.

```
class MainFeed extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 100 + "%", height: 100 + "%" }}>
        <View style={styles.tempNav}>
          <Text style={circle(backgroundColor="white")}>Text Here</Text>


        </View>
        <PostFeed />
      </View>
    );
}

  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tempNav: {
    width: 100 + "%", 
    height: 56,
    marginTop: 20, 
    backgroundColor: "rgb(250,250,250)",
    borderBottomColor: "rgb(102,102,102)",
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"

  },
});


var circle = function setTextColor() {

  myVar = setTimeout(setTextColor, 500);

  var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

  var ColorValue = "FFFFFF"; // default color - white (index = 0)

  if (index == 1) ColorValue = "FFCCCC"; //peach
  if (index == 2) ColorValue = "CCAFFF"; //violet
  if (index == 3) ColorValue = "A6BEFF"; //lt blue
  if (index == 4) ColorValue = "99FFFF"; //cyan
  if (index == 5) ColorValue = "D5CCBB"; //tan
  if (index == 6) ColorValue = "99FF99"; //lt green
  if (index == 7) ColorValue = "FFFF99"; //lt yellow
  if (index == 8) ColorValue = "FFCC99"; //lt orange
  if (index == 9) ColorValue = "CCCCCC"; //lt grey

  // document.querySelector(".circle").style.color =
  //   "#" + ColorValue;
  return {
    color: circle,
  }
}

export default MainFeed;
```

Comment: Howdy, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? It's unclear.

Comment: I would like the function to change the text color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the style in the state, in the `setTimeout` set the color to the one returned by the function. Your code needs some clean up.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

class MainFeed extends React.Component {

  state = {
    textStyle: {
      color: 'green',
    }
  }

  setTextColor = () => {


  var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

  var ColorValue = "#FFFFFF"; // default color - white (index = 0)

  if (index == 1) ColorValue = "#FFCCCC"; //peach
  if (index == 2) ColorValue = "#CCAFFF"; //violet
  if (index == 3) ColorValue = "#A6BEFF"; //lt blue
  if (index == 4) ColorValue = "#99FFFF"; //cyan
  if (index == 5) ColorValue = "#D5CCBB"; //tan
  if (index == 6) ColorValue = "#99FF99"; //lt green
  if (index == 7) ColorValue = "#FFFF99"; //lt yellow
  if (index == 8) ColorValue = "#FFCC99"; //lt orange
  if (index == 9) ColorValue = "#CCCCCC"; //lt grey

  // document.querySelector(".circle").style.color =
  //   "#" + ColorValue;
  return {
    color: ColorValue,
  }
}

  componentDidMount = () => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        textStyle: this.setTextColor()
      })
    }, 1000);

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 100 + "%", height: 100 + "%" }}>
        <View style={styles.tempNav}>
          <Text style={this.state.textStyle}>Text Here</Text>


        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tempNav: {
    width: 100 + "%", 
    height: 56,
    marginTop: 20, 
    backgroundColor: "rgb(250,250,250)",
    borderBottomColor: "rgb(102,102,102)",
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"

  },
});

export default MainFeed;
```

see this snack https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/vengeful-chocolates

Comment: color changes, but it's not constantly updated like i had hoped(changes once at start). i'd like the text to scan thru the colors or even a gradient of rainbow colors. i'm pretty new to programming, this is just a little side thing i'd like to have in this app i'm learning to build. it's really not super important, and I think i might not be using stackoverflow right, trying to get help doing things instead of help with debugging. i wouldn't be offended if you didn't come back to make it scan thru colors like i am hoping for. your help got me a lot closer, ty. i'll upvote when i figure out how

Comment: @Meowterspace for that you'll need `setInterval` see my updated snack https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/vengeful-chocolates

Answer (score 1):

What you have is close to working, but you have a number of bugs in your color changing method:

1. It's returning an object `{ "color": circle }`, and in this case circle is a function. That should be `{color: ColorValue }`
2. Your color values are all missing the '#'

Additionally, you're missing a few key concepts from React:

1. Use state. Updating the state triggers the render() method by default.
2. Use lifecycle method to call the change color method.
3. Don't return the entire css style object, just the value for the css `color` property.

See this Fiddle for an example to get you closer to a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/8x6af9u5/

Comment: maybe he should  create a colors.js. Then use colors.red, colors.blue